# Show data from Combobox in DatagridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to show data from combobox in datagridview, but with my code show only id not data,

i use this code :

> ```
>     public List<Object> findAllForCombo()
>         {
>         return (from klienti in borgjlitEntities.Klientis
>                 select new
>                 {
>                     klienti.KlientiId,
>                     emri = klienti.Emri + " " +klienti.Mbiemri,
>                     klienti.QytetiId,
>                     klienti.Ndermarrja
>                 }).ToList<Object>();
>     }
> ```
>
> `QytetiId` is ID of ComboBox.

Comment: What's the DataTextField of your ComboBox?

Comment: @sq33G it is Varchar(50)

Comment: ....Are you using Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Comment: ...i am using Windows Forms

Comment: OK, so then my question becomes, "What is your [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.80).aspx)?"

Comment: this.cmbQytetiId.DataSource = qi.findAll();
            cmbQytetiId.DisplayMember = "Emri";
            cmbQytetiId.ValueMember = "QytetiId";

"Emri" is "Name of column wher are name of data "

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood your question but I think your code seems OK. Could you provide some sample source (a list) and show what you want your combobox to display?